# Compensation for cancelled flight - how long to wait?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, compensation, british-airways

Just over a month ago, my flight with BA from Boston (BOS) to London (LHR) was cancelled about half a day prior to departure, after I already checked in online. Long story short, I finally made it to London over 24 hours later than originally planned. While speaking with the customer service to rebook on another flight, I was told that the reason for cancellation was "shortage of aircraft".

A few days later I submitted a compensation claim to BA for the late arrival (£520) plus actual expenses during the extra stay in Boston.  Considering this was for a family of 5, the total compensation amount is a bit under £3,000.

When I submitted the claim, I received a response that "due to a very high number of requests, it may take some time to process my claim", etc, etc.

My question is: how long do I wait before I start escalating?  It's been 5 weeks since I submitted the claim. And, the follow-up question: how do I escalate?

Comment: Usually contacting the airline Twitter page by DM is a great way to get hold of them

Comment: While there might be extra steps for your claim as it is quite high value, my compensation claim for a diverted (domestic UK) BA flight literally took about 15 days from submission to receiving a cheque (which I received 2 days ago) so their claims department is not THAT busy...

Comment: @etmuse Thanks - this gives a reference point. I have written to them again (there was a link in the original email confirming my claim). I also wrote to them on facebook.  I'll wait another week and then see what/where I may be able to escalate

Answer (score 2):

According to EU261 the airline has 6 weeks to reply. After that you can make a complain to the national enforcement body. In your case you are actually covered by UK261 instead, but I assume it's the same.
Once I filled a claim with the now defunct wow air and they took exactly 6 weeks to reply.